# Showing the equivalence between the chain rule's Leibniz and Lagrange Notations

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, notation, calculus, variational-calculus

This may seem more math related but this question crossed my mind as I was reading the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange Equation.

In math, we were introduced to the Lagrange notation of the derivative chain rule with a demonstration as to why it's true.
In physics, it is more practical to use the Leibniz notation, which is equivalent to the Lagrange one. [On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), this is how the equivalence is shown:

> write the chain rule in Lagrange notation as follows
> $$F^{'}=f^{'}(g(x))g^{'}(x).$$
> The chain rule may also be rewritten in Leibniz's notation in the following way. If the variable $z$ depends on the variable $y$, which itself depends on the variable $x$ (i.e., $y$ and $z$ are dependent variables), then $z$, via the intermediate variable of $y$, depends on $x$ as well. In which case, the chain rule states that:
> $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$$
> More precisely, to indicate the point each derivative is evaluated at, the
> chain rule states
> $$\frac{dz}{dx}\biggr\rvert_{x} =\frac{dz}{dy}\biggr\rvert_{y(x)} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}\biggr\rvert_{x}.$$
> The versions of the chain rule in the Lagrange and Leibniz notation are equivalent, in the sense that $z=f(y)$ and $y=g(x)$ so that
> $$\frac{dz}{dx}\biggr\rvert_{x} = (f\!\circ\!g)^{'}\!(x)$$
> and
> $$\frac{dz}{dy}\biggr\rvert_{y(x)} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}\biggr\rvert_{x}=f^{'}(y(x))g^{'}(x)=f^{'}(g(x))g^{'}(x).$$

However, I do not fully understand the equivalence because of the following confusion:

The prime in the Lagrange notation refers to the derivative of f with respect to x, while in the leibniz notation it refers to the derivative of f with respect to y. So the same symbol refers to two different things and the equivalence is not really clear.

The way i understand it is so that what to show should be:

**the derivative of f with respect to x with g(x)=y as an argument of f, or d(f)/dx (y)**

should be the same as

**the derivative of f with respect to the function y=g(x), or d(f)/dy**

which, from first sight, is not the same thing, as deriving f with respect to y is not the same as putting y as an argument in the derivative of f with respect to x.

I'll be thankful for any answer!

Comment: It's been suggested that this would be appropriate on [math.se] but is off topic here. We can migrate it if that's the case, but I wonder what other people think? I know math questions in a physical context are on topic for us, but there's not much context here.

Comment: You're right that in the Leibniz notation, the $z$ means completely different things on the LHS and the RHS. Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270436/568204 In this previous answer of mine, I elaborate on how to properly interpret the equalities using Leibniz notation, and some of the things to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule appears when differentiating composition of functions. Suppose 
\begin{equation*}
 f:B \rightarrow C, g: A \rightarrow B 
\end{equation*}

You can compose them as $f \circ g : A \rightarrow C$. So if you want to find the change of $f \circ g $ (in $C$, since this is the image) in terms of a variation in $A$ you may use Chain Rule $f \circ g '(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$. Now, what is $f'$?, well you know how to see rate of changes in $C$, so $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to something in $B$, and equally for $g'$, it is the change of $g$ with respect to something in $A$.

So the different notations mean the same, on one hand, in the Lagrange notation, the derivative of $f$ is with respect to something in its image (if its only a 1 variable function, then you can differentiate it with respect to it, and then evaluate it where you want it) evaluated at the point $g(x)$. And the so called, Leibiz notation, you are doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Lagrange notation, $f'(arg)$ refers to the derivative of $f$ with respect to $arg$. For example, $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, while $f'(g(x))$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $g(x)$. If we define $y=g(x)$, then $f'(g(x))=f'(y)=\frac{df}{dy}$.

Answer (score 0):

The prime notation $f'$ does not mean the derivative with respect to the variable called $x$. It means the derivative with respect to the argument of $f$. Often the argument of $f$ is called "$x$" so both ways are equivalent. But in your case the argument of $f$ is $g(x)$.

To write it out explicitly,

$$
f'(\text{whatever}) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(\text{whatever}+h)-f(\text{whatever})}{h}.
$$

In your case: $\text{whatever}=g(x)$.